# Emulating a different CPU architecture per a VM on VMware ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi, cpu-architecture

I currently have a VMWare ESXI server. We plan on having some build machines for compiling and testing software however we've run into a problem.

All of the CPUs that the software will end up running on are i586 however, our VM server is new so when we install the VM the cpu ends up being x86-64. This then causes issues as libraries that are built on i586 are incompatible with x86-64.

Is there a way we can tell the VM to emulate the VM CPU as i586 to match are our normal servers?

Thanks

Comment: You are aware that the i586 platform is (a)32 bit and (b) the PENTIUM generation. As in Pentium 100. As in - nearly 20 years old, iirc.

Comment: VMWare uses the physical processor cycles to run instruction sets.  This means it communicates directly with the processor and does not change the instructions or present different architectures to the guest VM.  What you want to accomplish is not possible with VMWare ESXi.

Comment: As long as you are installing a 32bit OS in your VM it shouldn't be an issue. Just tell your compiler what processor you want it to compile for.

Comment: I feel a bit thick now, having a bad day I think. I didn't realise the DVD I picked up was 64 bit, reinstalled with an actual x86 version and CPU shows as i586 as expected

Answer (score 2):

Not quite... I'd use a combination of techniques.

- You will want to build a 32-bit virtual machine.
- Use a period-correct OS. Maybe?
- You could investigate [CPU capability masking](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1993) to eliminate newer features. This can be configured on a per-VM level, but is probably not needed.
- *Right-size* the VM to your reference architecture. If the target system only has an i586 with 128MB RAM and one CPU, your VM should look like that. Also, if the CPU is 200MHz, limit the VM to that amount.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit computer. Just install a 32-bit OS on your VMs, and you will have no compatibility issues at all.